# Display comments from other nodes with a reference

Tags: 7, comments, views, entities

Here's a doozy.

I have a certain content type where nodes of this ct serve as a sort of portal for other nodes. The other nodes (which are all different content types themselves) have entity reference fields, linked too this portal-node.

I need a view that displays the latest -comments- of the nodes linked too the portal node which the user is currently viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't get this to work with views, so I wrote a custom module with an sql query. Not very clean, but it does the trick.